# Application or object defined error. Run time error 1004

Tags: excel

```
Cells.Sort Key1:=Range(rng1), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range(rng2) _
  , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
  False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, DataOption2 _
  :=xlSortNormal
```

It's throwing an error called application error or object defined error.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code. What is `rng1` ? What is `rng2` ? What is `Cells` ? You've omitted the declaration and assignment of these critical components.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sort operation coding alternative. It is pared down to only what you absolutely need.

```
dim rng1 as range, rng2 as range

With ActiveSheet   '<-set this properly as With Sheets("Sheet1")
    set rng1 = .Range("A1")   'Top cell of the primary sort key
    set rng2 = .Range("B1")   'Top cell of the secondary sort key
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion        '<-sort the 'island' of data that surrounds A1 (with a header)
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=rng1, Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Key2:=rng2, Order2:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End With
```